# Uniform file access

Tags: algorithm, file, iterator

Let's say I've got a file, each line containing a word. It is sorted in alphabetical order. I want to write a program to process each line in the file, one by one. But not in the alphabetical ordering currently in the file. At every step, the processed lines should be approximately uniformly distributed within the file. That is, the line numbers of the already processed lines should be reasonably spread out from line 0 to line max.

The lesser the footprint the better, as the file can be quite large. And bonus points to answers with a deterministic approach, so it's possible to save the current position and pick up where you last left off. The ideal answer takes only the total number of lines and the current line as inputs, and have the next line as output. It also describes an efficient way of mapping line numbers to file positions.

Examples in any programming language, with an explanation are encouraged!

Comment: Bonus points to questions that show an attempt at solving the problem oneself. The ideal question would include a self-answer.

Comment: @Dukeling I was just trying to make clear what the actual question was about, [not be vague](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I asked the question _because_ I didn't know the answer.

Comment: I was just pointing out basically the same thing as the "Search, and research" part of what you linked - "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not see how to solve the problem of finding a specific line only by its line number, if the length of each line differs.
[If you have enough RAM, you can iterate the file once and create an array of indexes, where each line starts.]

But if you only want to iterate through the lines in a near an order different to the order in the file, you could do something like this:

```
N : Number of lines in the file
p : big prime number which is no divisor of N 
    (e.g. take one that is much bigger than N)
l : number of the last line read

nextLineNumberToRead= (l+p) % N
```

This will iterate through all lines.

P.s.
Reading a file in a non linear way decreases performance of file reading quite heavily because caching of you storage device is optimized to handle linear access and also a lot of storage devices like disc drives are designed for linear access.

Answer (score 1):

A very good way to generate the next line number from the current line number:

```
Let LIM = least power of 2 >= number of lines in file
Let CNT = size of LIM in bits, that is CNT = log2(LIM)
repeat until LINE <= number of lines in file {
   reverse the order of the low CNT bits in LINE
   increment LINE by 1
   reverse the order of the low CNT bits in LINE
}
```

This guarantees the most even distribution of processed lines at every step.

Comment: This is essentially "the rational-number-generating function such that it takes, as input, one rational number and returns the next in sequence" referenced by @High Performance Mark.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside many practicalities I'll assume that you have a file system and file design which support random access to the file by line number so that you can read arbitrary lines in any sequence you like.  If this burns out your disks or takes until the end of time, well that's your look out.

Write a function to generate the following sequence of rational numbers:

```
1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 7/8, 3/8, 5/8, 1/16, 15/16, ...
```

you should see where this is going by now.

Take those rational numbers and multiply them by the number of lines in the file.  Now you have a sequence of line numbers approximately uniformly distributed throughout the file.  At each step you only need to record the most-recently-used rational number.  If you had the foresight to write the rational-number-generating function such that it takes, as input, one rational number and returns the next in sequence you have your restart capability already.

If you can't turn this into working code in your favourite language, shame on you.

Comment: To avoid reading any line more than once, with your approach, you need that the number of lines is a power of 2. But I still like it very much.